# Edit filepath PHP

Tags: php, filepath

I have a delete button on my page, that delete button has to delete a certain entry in my database (not too difficult), it has to delete the entire folder where the file that holds the delete button is in (also doable), but I also want it to delete another folder that's placed somewhere else and I'm not sure how to do that. Using

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

I am able to get the filepath where the file holding the delete button is located. That results in this:

```
mywebsite.nl/subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/s-gravenmoer/aandrijvingenenbesturingen/logo4life
```

The filepath that I also want to delete is quite similair, but a little different. The last 3 folders a variable, so their lenght (in characters) is always different. However, the second to last folder has to be deleted from this filepath so this remains:

```
 mywebsite.nl/subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/s-gravenmoer/logo4life
```

Is there a way to do this with PHP? Using substr or something like that perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$folderToRemove = preg_replace( '#^(.*)/(.*?)/(.*?)$#', "$1/$3", dirname(__FILE__) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using "glob." Details in [www.php.net/glob](http://www.php.net/glob)

You can try:

```
$files = glob('subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/*/logo4life');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    unlink($file); // note that this is very dangerous though, you may end up deleting a lot of files
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I went and took the less dangerous method ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything fancy, as you guessed, a simple str_replace will do it:-

```
$file = 'mywebsite.nl/subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/s-gravenmoer/aandrijvingenenbesturingen/logo4life';
var_dump(str_replace('aandrijvingenenbesturingen/', '', $file));
```

Output:-

```
string 'mywebsite.nl/subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/s-gravenmoer/logo4life' (length=62)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work, since the last 3 folders are variable, aandrijvingenenbesturingen isn't always just that..

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "mywebsite.nl/subdomains/dongen/httpdocs/s-gravenmoer/aandrijvingenenbesturingen/logo4life";
$regex = "/(.*\/).*\/(.*)/";
$matches = array();
preg_match($regex,  $path, $matches);
// var_dump($matches);
$new_path = $matches[1].$matches[2];
echo $new_path;
```

Above code uses `preg_match` for matching a regexp in a string.